# Opening File GDB in Samba throws exception - but only in VS2010 debug mode

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase

I'm accessing a file geodatabase through a mapped network drive pointing to a unix machine running Samba.

When I start the app from within VS2010, I get a COM exception when I attempt to open the file Gdb.  No exception is thrown when not running in the debugger.

I'm using the [recommended method](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/c778d2bb-eb36-4793-9c89-20795811c5eb.htm#File) of opening the gdb (via Activator.CreateInstance):

```
public static IWorkspace FileGdbWorkspaceFromPropertySet(String database)
{
   IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySetClass();
   propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", database);
  Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(
    "esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory");
  IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)
    Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
  return workspaceFactory.Open(propertySet, 0);
}
```

If I copy the same file gdb to the local windows machine, I can access it without any exception.

Has anyone ever run into this issue?

I know very little about Samba - is there something that needs to be configured to make it more file gdb friendly?

Comment: Did you try running VS2010 in Administrator mode.  Seems like a domain permissions issue honestly.  I've had trouble instantiating on a different thread, but that's obviously not your issue.